# Is there a way how to fix the Compile error in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, compiler-errors

I'm trying to get some tables from the web to put in excel and in my VBA code. I'm receiving an error on VBA below. I will post my code so someone can check where the error is, and what I need to do to fix the compile error that I'm getting.

[image: Problem pic]

```vb
Sub GoToSpace()
Dim BaseURL As String
Dim NextURL As String
Dim DateOptions As Selenium.WebElements
Dim DateOption As Selenium.WebElement
Dim tbls As Selenium.WebElements
Dim t As Selenium.WebElement
Dim ws As Worksheet

BaseURL = "https://finance.yahoo.com/qoute/SPCE/options"
Set cd = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
cd.Start
cd.Get BaseURL
cd.FindElementByCss("button").Click
Set DateOptions = cd.FindElementsByCss("option")
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

For Each DateOption In DateOptions
      NextURL = BaseURL & "?date=" & DateOption.Attribute("value")
      cd.ExecuteScript "window.open(arguments[0])", NextURL
      cd.SwitchToNextWindow
      Set tbls = cd.FindElementsByCss("table")
      
      For Each t In tbls
         t.AsTable.ToExcel ws.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
         Next t

      cd.Window.Close
      cd.SwitchToPreviousWindow
      Next DateOption
      
      ws.Range("A1").Value = Now
      ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like you need to set "Dim cd" under "Dim ws As worksheet"

Comment: Do you have a reference to the Selenium type library under Tools > References?

Comment: No, i don't have that

Comment: If an error occurs, point out in which line of your code it pops up. This makes it easier for everyone to help fix a problem. Otherwise everyone's is just guessing as to what the offending line/cause may be.